# socket.io, getting io is not defined on console

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io

I am setting a basic chat app using sockets, but in the initial stage of programming I am getting this error: “io is not defined” on the client side.

I have tried including the CDN and adding 
*<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>*,
but no success.

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
```

**script.js**

```
let socket = io();

console.log("socket formed on " + socket.id)
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const socketio = require('socket.io')
const http = require('http')

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = socketio(server)

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'frontend')))

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log("New socket formed fksrom " + socket.id)
})

server.listen(2345, () => console.log('website open on http://localhost:2345'))
```

I expect the socket ID to be shown in the console,
but on console it is displaying “io is not defined”.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check if document has loaded so here's the code below:

```
// Pure Javascript
if(document.readyState === "complete") {
  //Already loaded!
}
else {
  //Add onload or DOMContentLoaded event listeners here: for example,
  window.addEventListener("onload", function () {/* Move your code here */}, false);
  //or
  //document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {/* code */}, false);
}
```

Since you already have jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /** Your code here */
})
```

You're trying to access a script before it is loaded so the above code should help you run your script only when you've done with loading the jQuery library and socket.io.js library.